# Why does the wall-mounted control for my Genie 2024 Garage Opener quit working when the weather is hot?

Tags: garage-door-opener

Remotes work fine.  But every time the temperature gets above 80 the light in the wall unit (inside) goes out and it quits working.  Usually by the next morning it comes back on.  Since we're having an unusually warm summer the unit never does work.

Comment: what other things have you checked, besides the indicator light?

Comment: Check all the terminal connections. It could be that metal expansion is causing one of them to fail.